# Multiple definition when linking file generated by protocol buffer compiler

Tags: c++, linker, protocol-buffers, linker-errors, grpc

I have a program, which is linking static library. The program uses gRPC for the communication, but the library which is linked to the program uses gRPC also. The library is provided by 3RD party as binary file. When I am building the program, I get linker error:

> /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a(repeated_field.o): In function
>   `google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::InternalExtend(int)':
>   /usr/local/include/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc:48:
>   multiple definition of
>   `google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::InternalExtend(int)'
>   /opt/shared/code/lib/libadapter.a(repeated_field.o):/opt/shared/grpc/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc:46:
>   first defined here

There is collision between gRPC used in file automatically generated by protocol buffer compiler and gRPC which is part of static library, because my code is empty main function :)

The problem appears, when I add file automatically generated from .proto file (driver.pb.cc). When I remove the line with this file in cmake, multiple definition problem is gone.

I am using CMAKE for the compilation, interesting parts:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE (${PROJECT_NAME}
  driver.pb.cc  # when commented, there is no linking error
  driver.cc
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}
    adapter.a
    grpc++_unsecure
    protobuf
)
```

driver.cc:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
```

driver.pb.cc:

```
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: driver.proto
// and so forth .................................
```

Anyway, the file `driver.pb.cc` is fine, when I don't link static library, the communication client-server works with this file.

The questions:

- can I expect there is some problem with 3RD party library and should I maybe report the bug? Will they be able to fix it? How?
- how can I solve (workaround) this problem? The problem is between automatically generated file and the library provided by 3RD party, but maybe I can workaround it somehow..

Comment: Show us the command-line invoked by cmake to link your target pleae (`VERBOSE=1 make`). It looks like you have *two* installations of protobuf on your system and both are linked.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, you see two paths in error output: '/usr/local/include/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc:48' and
/opt/shared/grpc/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc:46'. I can assure you the path '/opt/shared/gr...' is not on my computer. I believe it's the directory where the programmer building the library i am linking had gRPC project in.

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: This means `adapter.a` you link against already contains all of protobuf symbols, linked statically. Does removing protobuf completely from your cmake file resolves your link?

Comment: => `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} adapter.a grpc++_unsecure)`

Comment: When I do what you suppose, I get: `driver.pb.cc:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to \`google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptorsTable*)'`, and many more similar errors. I think only part of protobuf comes with the library, that's why there is this error. Also it's different "older" version of protobuf, I should probably use mine protobuf version, which was used to generate pb file.